# Calculating if a point is within a polygon, or outside of it

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, computational-geometry

Here is the function (along with its support functions):

```
def findAnglesBetweenTwoVectors(v1s, v2s):
    dot_v1_v2 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', v1s, v2s)
    dot_v1_v1 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', v1s, v1s)
    dot_v2_v2 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', v2s, v2s)

    return np.arccos(dot_v1_v2/(np.sqrt(dot_v1_v1*dot_v2_v2)))

def calculateDirectionOfRayNotParallelToAnyEdgeOfPolygon(vertices, difference = 1e-2, referenceDirectionVector = np.array([1, 0]), maxWhileTime = 0.5):

    relevantVectors = vertices - np.roll(vertices, 1, axis = 0)
    angles = findAnglesBetweenTwoVectors(relevantVectors, np.repeat([referenceDirectionVector], len(relevantVectors), axis=0))
    angles = np.append(angles, np.pi+angles)

    for x in xrange(50):
        direction = random.random()*2*np.pi
        if np.all(np.abs(angles-direction) >= difference):
            return direction

    raise StandardError("No direction found!")

def calculateNumberOfBoundaryIntersections(point, direction, vertices):

    neighbourVertices = np.roll(vertices, 1, axis = 0)
    ss = neighbourVertices - vertices

    r = produceDirectionVectorGivenDirection(direction)

    qs_minus_p = vertices - point
    r_cross_ss = np.cross(r, ss)

    ts = np.cross(qs_minus_p, ss)/r_cross_ss
    if 0 in ts:
        return 1

    us = np.cross((qs_minus_p), r)/r_cross_ss

    return np.sum((ts >= 0) & (us >= 0) & (us < 1))

def isPointWithinPolygon(point, polygonVertexCoords):
    fixedDirection = calculateDirectionOfRayNotParallelToAnyEdgeOfPolygon(polygonVertexCoords)

    numberOfBoundaryIntersections = calculateNumberOfBoundaryIntersections(point, fixedDirection, polygonVertexCoords)

    if numberOfBoundaryIntersections%2 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

The program itself is based on a simple discrete version of the Jordan curve theorem: if a point is inside of a polygon, then a ray emanating from it in a direction that is not parallel to any of the edges of the polygon will cross the polygon boundary an odd number of times. If the point is not inside the polygon, the ray will cross the polygon boundary an even number of times.

The boundary intersection calculation logic is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14318254/3486684) and then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565282/3486684).

Earlier, I used a different algorithm which spent a lot of time in `findAnglesBetweenTwoVectors`. Through a code review I performed here, we determined that it was unlikely we could optimize that function anymore. After I changed the boundary intersection logic, I spend a lot more time in `calculateNumberOfBoundaryIntersections`, with a small performance gain over the old algorithm.

So, while it is unlikely that performance can be squeezed out of `findAnglesBetweenTwoVectors` I suppose the other functions are still up for grabs.

Once again, this is a place where my code spends a lot of time (75% of the total time!), so optimizing it could lead to major performance gains for me. Is my NumPy usage good?

**EDIT:** I just achieved a moderate gain by changing the organization of the code so that it is like this:

```
def determineUnitVectorNotParallelToAnyEdgeOfPolygon(vertices):
    edges = np.roll(vertices, 1, axis = 0) - vertices

    for x in range(100):
        direction = 2*np.pi*random.random()
        directionVector = np.array([np.cos(direction), np.sin(direction)])

        if 0 not in np.cross(edges, directionVector):
            return directionVector

def calculateNumberOfBoundaryIntersections(point, directionVector, vertices):

    neighbourVertices = np.roll(vertices, 1, axis = 0)
    ss = neighbourVertices - vertices

    r = directionVector

    qs_minus_p = vertices - point
    r_cross_ss = np.cross(r, ss)

    ts = np.cross(qs_minus_p, ss)/r_cross_ss
    if 0 in ts:
        return 1

    us = np.cross((qs_minus_p), r)/r_cross_ss

    return np.sum((ts >= 0) & (us >= 0) & (us < 1))

def isPointWithinPolygon(point, polygonVertexCoords):
    numberOfBoundaryIntersections = calculateNumberOfBoundaryIntersections(point, determineUnitVectorNotParallelToAnyEdgeOfPolygon(polygonVertexCoords), polygonVertexCoords)

    if numberOfBoundaryIntersections%2 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Can we use matplotlib/numpy, or do you want pure python?

Comment: @brechmos No rules at all! Let's use whatever we can to get as much performance as we can!

Comment: You are unnecessarily complicating things. `scikit-image` has a working implementation of the point in polygon algorithm in Cython [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/_shared/geometry.pyx#L7), and you may want to check the discussion [here](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) for details on the algorithm, although the code presented is all C.

Comment: @Jaime Hm. How come that algorithm works by always choosing the same fixed direction?

Comment: @Jaime Ah! It seems that that methodology doesn't work for convex polygons...

Comment: What do you call a convex polygon? In my experience it works for any polygon. Where did you get that the direction must not be parallel to a polygon's side? With the way crossings are detected in the articles linked, it still results in correct results.

Comment: @Jaime I got that from a math book, but perhaps I am not understanding correctly. Anyway, this seems like the best solution! Thanks a lot for pointing me to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had to write an roipoly in python/numpy/matplotlib as I use that a lot for my work (and I liked the one in Matlab).  So here is my implementation of roipoly:

```
def roipoly():
    XY = ginput(-1)

    nrows = sum( abs( r_[ gcf().get_axes()[0].get_xbound() ] ) )
    ncols = sum( abs( r_[ gcf().get_axes()[0].get_ybound() ] ) )
    nrows,ncols = int(nrows), int(ncols)

    path = matplotlib.path.Path( XY )
    mask = array([ path.contains_point((j,i)) for i in range(nrows) for j in range(ncols)  ]).reshape(ncols,nrows)

    return mask
```

If I understand the problem, I am guessing you could adapt so it would be something like:

```
def isPointWithinPolygon(point, polygonVertexCoords):
     path = matplotlib.path.Path( polygonVertexCoords )
     return path.contains_point(point[0], point[1])
```

I am not completely sure point and polygonVertexCoords are going to be in the same format, but maybe this would be a start.

I am not going to claim this is the most efficient method, but is a method. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One may also solve for the [generalized barycentric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) coordinates: at least one of them must be negative for points outside the convex hull of the polytope, see for example this thesis on [On Generalized Barycentric Coordinates...](http://domino.mpi-inf.mpg.de/intranet/ag4/ag4publ.nsf/0/bfaf8554e927cbb8c125752400480229/%24FILE/thesis.pdf)

Comment: would you mind including at least pseudocode? I think no one really wants to skim a 160 pages dissertation for an algorithm. Currently this answer is also no more than a link. While I *believe* you might be correct, I'd also like to see the contents of the link summarized, in case the link goes down...